# How to measure CPU based on a threshold

Tags: windows, cpu-usage

We are tracking down the resource requirement for our production environment(windows). I need to find out the maximum CPU and memory utilization. I do understand that we can use the wmic command to record that. the problem in that is, I don't want to run the command frequently.

Is there a way to trigger the batch when the server CPU/memory hits a threshold value?

It will be great if you could share your views :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use a monitoring solution.
The problem is that they are either cost money (e.g. SCOM, PRTG) , runs on Linux (and for Windows-folk like me is a real bummer) (e.g. Nagios Core, Munin), or just too complex (e.g. Pandora).

Anyway, if you want just to trigger a script by CPU usage you could do that easily by setting performance monitor to create an event, and then attach a task to that event, as [demonstrated here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/netgeneral/Scripted-Networt-Defense-Part2.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to measure, and don't need a long term solution. You can get a free trial of SPLUNK

> http://www.splunk.com/en_us/products/splunk-enterprise.html

From this you can use a process-monitor to monitor CPU/Memory Usage on your hosts.

It's primary purpose is log collection, but there are a lot of helpful addons.